# What was runlevel 4 used for with SysV init?

Tags: sysvinit, runlevel, sysv

I'm reading about SysV init and I see there are levels 0-6.

[image]

I understand that level 4 could be defined by the OS operator for special purposes, but I'm having trouble thinking of any examples.

Has anyone seen runlevel 4 used in the wild? What was it used for? I assume a trigger for changing the runlevel to 4 also had to be created, since the system would never automatically go into level 4?

Comment: Slackware uses runlevel 4 for [multiuser with display manager](http://www.slackware.com/config/init.php), but if you’re only interested in systems strictly adhering to the LSB definition, that’s not relevant.

Comment: @StephenKitt none the less, I find that interesting. It's as if they thought level 4 was pointless and shifted 5 to 4. It may be pointless for me to specify sysV, as `systemd` still makes use of these same run levels.

Comment: Slackware is older than the LSB, I don’t know off-hand if there was a “reference runlevel 5” when runlevel 4 was chosen for this in Slackware ;-).

Comment: [JdeBP’s page on the topic](http://jdebp.eu/FGA/system-5-rc-problems.html) suggests there wasn’t.

Comment: Strictly, this is the van Smoorenburg clone that you are asking about, as that's what that table applies to.  Actual AT&T Unix System 5 `init`/`rc` was a completely different kettle of fish.  Note that Wikipedia is iffy on this subject, as is all too common.

Comment: This topic may be better over on the [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). There aren't any major Unices still using SysVInit.